# Как записать в background миниатюру

Tags: wordpress

Это вывод второй миниатюры поста, как можно её записать в фон?
`<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) :
MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');
endif;?>`

Как вывести в `background: url();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body style="background: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); ?>');">
```